# Rewriting a proxied upstream

Tags: nginx, rewrite, reverse-proxy

I have a server which serves `LuCI` for me on `localhost:8080`. I'm trying to proxy to it via nginx, but I'd like to rewrite the URLs so that instead of `https://myserver/cgi-bin/luci`, I have `https://myserver/`.

Here's what I've got so far, which doesn't seem to be working:

```
upstream luci {
    server localhost:8080;
}

server {
    # ...
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://luci;
        proxy_redirect / /cgi-bin/luci;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

However, with this configuration, I'm still seeing my urls prefixed with `/cgi-bin/luci`, and they still work somehow.

How can I rewrite my incoming requests from `https://myserver/^(.*)$` to `http://luci/cgi-bin/luci$1`?